# Is it possible to fetch many objects together from Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv

We have about 5,000 objects of class Domain in Google App Engine, and we want to export the list of domains to CSV. Each domain is linked to an object of class DomainStateData:

```
class DomainStateData(db.Expando, ExpandoEntity):
    plan = db.ReferenceProperty(Plan)
    plan_expiration = db.DateTimeProperty()
    trial_expiration = db.DateTimeProperty()

    date_created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True, indexed=True)
    last_modified = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)


class Domain(db.Expando, ExpandoEntity, SocialIconsEntity):
    """
    Domain Model
    """
    domain = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    ...
    _state_data = db.ReferenceProperty(DomainStateData)

    @property
    def state_data(self):
        try:
            if not self._state_data:
                # try to get it, if not, build it
                sd = DomainStateData.get_by_key_name(self.key().name())
                if not sd:
                    sd = DomainStateData(key_name=self.key().name()).put()
                self._state_data = sd
                self.put()
                return self._state_data
            else:
                return self._state_data
        except ReferencePropertyResolveError:
            self._state_data = DomainStateData(key_name=self.key().name()).put()
            self.put()
            return self._state_data
```

I wrote a code which exports 100 domains to CSV (it takes 5 seconds), but if I try to fetch all the 5,000 domains I get a timeout, which is 60 seconds. Is it possible to fetch all the DomainStateData objects together without a timeout? Here is my code that exports the domains to CSV:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'libs')

import webapp2
import datetime
import csv
from models import Domain


class ExportAllDomainsToCsvHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
        self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="All Domains [{0}].csv"'.format(str(datetime.date.today()))
        writer = csv.writer(self.response.out)
        writer.writerow(["Domain", "Current state", "Plan expiration date", "Trial expiration date", "Current oauth user"])
        all_domains = Domain.all().fetch(100)
        all_domains.sort(key=lambda domain: (0 if domain.state_data.plan_expiration is None else 1, domain.state_data.plan_expiration, 0 if domain.state_data.trial_expiration is None else 1, domain.state_data.trial_expiration, domain.domain))
        for domain in all_domains:
            if (domain.state_data.plan_expiration is None):
                domain_plan_expiration = "No plan expiration date"
            else:
                domain_plan_expiration = domain.state_data.plan_expiration.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            if (domain.state_data.trial_expiration is None):
                domain_trial_expiration = "No trial expiration date"
            else:
                domain_trial_expiration = domain.state_data.trial_expiration.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            writer.writerow([domain.domain, domain.cur_state.name, domain_plan_expiration, domain_trial_expiration, domain.admin])


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ("/csv/export_all_domains_to_csv", ExportAllDomainsToCsvHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: look into using a task or a backend to generate the data on a long running (10 minutes or IIRC 60 on a backend) process then just pick it up when ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found a solution. I fetched all the DomainStateData objects directly from the database and now it takes 35 seconds to create the CSV with all the domains. Here is my code, I didn't change the models:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'libs')

import webapp2
import datetime
import csv
from models import DomainStateData, Domain


class ExportAllDomainsToCsvHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
        self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="All Domains [{0}].csv"'.format(str(datetime.date.today()))
        writer = csv.writer(self.response.out)
        writer.writerow(["Domain", "Current state", "Plan expiration date", "Trial expiration date", "Current oauth user"])
        all_domain_state_data_dict = dict()
        all_domain_state_data = DomainStateData.all().fetch(1000000)
        all_domains = Domain.all().fetch(1000000)
        for domain_state_data in all_domain_state_data:
            all_domain_state_data_dict[domain_state_data.key().name()] = domain_state_data
        for domain in all_domains:
            if (domain.key().name() in all_domain_state_data_dict):
                domain.__state_data = all_domain_state_data_dict[domain.key().name()]
        all_domains.sort(key=lambda domain: (0 if domain.__state_data.plan_expiration is None else 1, domain.__state_data.plan_expiration, 0 if domain.__state_data.trial_expiration is None else 1, domain.__state_data.trial_expiration, domain.domain))
        for domain in all_domains:
            if (domain.__state_data.plan_expiration is None):
                domain_plan_expiration = "No plan expiration date"
            else:
                domain_plan_expiration = domain.__state_data.plan_expiration.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            if (domain.__state_data.trial_expiration is None):
                domain_trial_expiration = "No trial expiration date"
            else:
                domain_trial_expiration = domain.__state_data.trial_expiration.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            writer.writerow([domain.domain, domain.cur_state.name, domain_plan_expiration, domain_trial_expiration, domain.admin])

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ("/csv/export_all_domains_to_csv", ExportAllDomainsToCsvHandler)
], debug=True)
```